# Как исправить заголовок файла в Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

При загрузке файла с русским именем на сайт он нормально сохраняется, но его заголовок (post_title) отображается в виде URL.

Скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Проблема появилась на нескольких сайтах. Подозреваю, что проблема из-за php.

Comment: Сайты эти на одном и том же хостинге?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решается через фильтр `attachment_fields_to_save`. Внутри фильтра просто присвойте нужный `post_title`. На основе имени файла, прогнанного через `urldecode`, например